# After reinstalling npm and cordova, "cordova -v" has no response

Tags: cordova

Sorry, my English is not good, I will try my best to describe my problem.
Today, I updated my node.js version, but then my cordova did not work anymore, so I reinstalled cordova, but it still didn't work.

After that, I uninstalled node.js and cordova, and reinstalled them, now `node -v` returns `v4.4.5` ,but `cordova -v` doesn't return anything.

1.My system is windows 7 ultimate 64 bit, and there was no error during cordova installation.

2. I used the command 'npm install cordova@6.1.1 -g' to install cordova;
3. even in my project file path ,cordova -v still didn't work ;
4. The npm bin directory is in my path.

Anyone having an idea on why it doesn't work?

```
C:\Windows\System32>cordova -v


C:\Windows\System32>node -v
v4.4.5
```

Comment: Did you get any error during cordova installation? Are you trying in mac or windows?

Comment: @Gandhi  My system is windows 7 ultimate,and there was no error during cordova installation.

Comment: we can check out this problem over team viewer session.is that OK for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Cordova command from the directory your cams was in during installation.

```
C:\yourprojectfilepath> cordova -v
```

If that works, you just didn't install globally.

Remove the node modules folder from that directory then run

```
npm install cordova -g
```

The -g flag indicates you wish to install globally. 
Then reopen your cams and try

```
cordova -v
```

If it's not recognized, check your path by running

```
echo %path%
```

to see if your npm bin directory is there, and if so, check if the Cordova.exe was installed somewhere else (can happen with multiple installations)

Comment: 1. I used the command 'npm install cordova@6.1.1 -g' to install cordova;2. even in my project file path ,cordova -v still didn't work ; 3. The npm bin directory is in my path.